# moment.js multiple live clocks using one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm building intranet project for my company, and there is a section for world clock which displays main world clocks like USA, Canada, UK, Australia ...etc.

I have completed it using moment.js + hero-face script, and ended with this after my customisation:

```js
var nightStart = 18,
    nightEnd = 6;
    
function updateClockUK() {
    var now = moment().tz("Europe/London"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $('#hero-uk').addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $('#hour-uk').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#minute-uk').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#second-uk').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function updateClockUS() {
    var now = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $('#hero-us').addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $('#hour-us').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#minute-us').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#second-us').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function updateClockCA() {
    var now = moment().tz("Canada/Eastern"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $('#hero-ca').addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $('#hour-ca').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#minute-ca').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#second-ca').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function updateClockSA() {
    var now = moment().tz("Asia/Riyadh"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $('#hero-sa').addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $('#hour-sa').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#minute-sa').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#second-sa').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function updateClockAU() {
    var now = moment().tz("Australia/Brisbane"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $('#hero-au').addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $('#hour-au').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#minute-au').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#second-au').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function updateClockNZ() {
    var now = moment().tz("Pacific/Auckland"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $('#hero-nz').addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $('#hour-nz').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#minute-nz').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#second-nz').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function timedUpdate() {
    updateClockUK();
    updateClockUS();
    updateClockCA();
    updateClockSA();
    updateClockAU();
    updateClockNZ();
    setTimeout(timedUpdate, 1000);
}

timedUpdate();
```

```css
.hero-circle {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:3.5px solid #F39C12;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3.5px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3), inset 0 1px 3.5px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3);
}
.hero-night {
    background-color: #805209;
}
.hero-face {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.hero-face:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    margin:-2.5px 0 0 -2.5px;
    background:#F39C12;
    border-radius:2.5px;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
.hero-hour {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-2px 0 -2px -25%;
    padding:2px 0 2px 25%;
    background:#F39C12;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 50%;
    transform-origin:100% 50%;
    border-radius:2px 0 0 2px;
}
.hero-minute {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-40% -1.25px 0;
    padding:40% 1.25px 0;
    background:#F39C12;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    transform-origin:50% 100%;
    border-radius:1.25px 1.25px 0 0;
}
.hero-second {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-40% -0.5px 0 0;
    padding:40% 0.5px 0;
    background:#F39C12;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    transform-origin:50% 100%;
}
.hero-title {
    text-align:center;
    font:14pt #000 bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timrwood/moment/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="hero-uk" class="hero-circle">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div id="hour-uk" class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div id="minute-uk" class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div id="second-uk" class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <div class="hero-title">UK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="hero-us" class="hero-circle">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div id="hour-us" class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div id="minute-us" class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div id="second-us" class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <div class="hero-title">USA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="hero-ca" class="hero-circle">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div id="hour-ca" class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div id="minute-ca" class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div id="second-ca" class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <div class="hero-title">Canada</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="hero-sa" class="hero-circle">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div id="hour-sa" class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div id="minute-sa" class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div id="second-sa" class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <div class="hero-title">KSA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="hero-au" class="hero-circle">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div id="hour-au" class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div id="minute-au" class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div id="second-au" class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <div class="hero-title">Australia</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="hero-nz" class="hero-circle">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div id="hour-nz" class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div id="minute-nz" class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div id="second-nz" class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <div class="hero-title">New Zealand</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle: World Clock #1](http://jsfiddle.net/yasserlotfy/vycLre3r/)

Now I want to convert this script to be smarter and less lines and functions.
I have ended up with this:

```js
var nightStart = 18,
    nightEnd = 6;

function updateClock() {
    var hero_tz = $(this).data("timezone"),
        now = moment().tz(hero_tz),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    if (now.hours() >= nightStart | now.hours() < nightEnd) {
        $(this).addClass("hero-night");
    }
    $(this).next('.hero-hour').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $(this).next('.hero-minute').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $(this).next('.hero-second').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function timedUpdate() {
    $(".hero-circle").each(updateClock);
    setTimeout(timedUpdate, 1000);
}

timedUpdate();
```

```css
.hero-circle {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:3.5px solid #F39C12;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3.5px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3), inset 0 1px 3.5px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3);
}
.hero-night {
    background-color: #805209;
}
.hero-face {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.hero-face:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    margin:-2.5px 0 0 -2.5px;
    background:#F39C12;
    border-radius:2.5px;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
.hero-hour {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-2px 0 -2px -25%;
    padding:2px 0 2px 25%;
    background:#F39C12;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 50%;
    transform-origin:100% 50%;
    border-radius:2px 0 0 2px;
}
.hero-minute {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-40% -1.25px 0;
    padding:40% 1.25px 0;
    background:#F39C12;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    transform-origin:50% 100%;
    border-radius:1.25px 1.25px 0 0;
}
.hero-second {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-40% -0.5px 0 0;
    padding:40% 0.5px 0;
    background:#F39C12;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 100%;
    transform-origin:50% 100%;
}
.hero-title {
    text-align:center;
    font:14pt #000 bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timrwood/moment/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <div class="hero-circle" data-timezone="America/Los_Angeles">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Clock title -->
        <div class="hero-title">America, Los Angeles</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <div class="hero-circle" data-timezone="Europe/London">
            <div class="hero-face">
                <div class="hero-hour"></div>
                <div class="hero-minute"></div>
                <div class="hero-second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Clock title -->
        <div class="hero-title">Europe, London</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle: World Clock #2](http://jsfiddle.net/yasserlotfy/xu99owad/)

But as you see it's not working, counters not moving like the first script.

Can you please help me fix this script to run in proper way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain in what ways it is not working

Comment: If you see the first script clocks working and counter clockwise updating every second, but the second script it's not working.

Comment: Please explain in what ways the second script is not working.

Comment: I have edited the post, Clock-Counters not moving (As the script not running in a proper way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the selector of element children,
It works perfectly now by changing:

```
$(this).next('.hero-*')
```

To be like this:

```
$(this).find('.hero-*')
```

Thanks to [Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter) for the hint.

Comment: I will share my code on Github to be available for everyone soon.
Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0):

In your script, replace `$(this).next()` with `$(this).first()`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, The problem was the selector.